# $ionicHistory backview()

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I would like to prompt the user with an alert in my ionic application only if the state name is "main.aaa"

I used the following code

```
if($ionicHistory.backView().stateName == 'main.aaa'){
      $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: '<h3 class="text-center">Please enter your information</h3>',
      okType: 'button button-primary-alert'
    })
 }
```

But, irrespective of the state name I'am always getting the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
if($state.$current.name == "main.aaa"){
    $ionicPopup.alert({
  title: '<h3 class="text-center">Please enter your information</h3>',
  okType: 'button button-primary-alert'
})
}
```

Hope this work for you..!

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/), this can be achieved by either using `$ionicHistory.currentStateName()` or `$ionicHistory.currentView().stateName`

The `$ionicHistory.backView()` is meant for retrieving information about the previous view. I am not sure why it is always showing an alert, but it may be that your previous view is always 'main.aaa' according to `$ionicHistory`.

Here are examples using the proposed methods with your code:

```
if($ionicHistory.currentStateName() == 'main.aaa') {
  $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: '<h3 class="text-center">Please enter your information</h3>',
    okType: 'button button-primary-alert'
  })
}
```

Or:

```
if($ionicHistory.currentView().stateName == 'main.aaa') {
  $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: '<h3 class="text-center">Please enter your information</h3>',
    okType: 'button button-primary-alert'
  })
}
```